# call contract function without a fullnode?

Tags: ether, mist

I have a contract that I deployed a while ago. My mist is like 6 months behind and I don't even think I have enough HD space for it to catch up. I can still launch it anyway to get contracts and wallets addresses etc. Is there anyway I can interact the same way I would when you click a contact and pick a function under the 'Write to contact' without having to download the fullnode?

Answer (score 0):

I used MEW https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts using the contract address and pasting in the ABI/JSON that you can copy from mist by clicking on 'show interface'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tour own node to work with Ethereum nowadays.  All you need is Web3-enabled browser, such as [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) + [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) or [Opera](https://www.opera.com/).  These browsers use free Ethereum nodes available in the cloud.

Then you need to open any Ethereum UI in such browser.  This could be [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com) or even [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) in case your contract's source code was verified on it.

Let me know if you need more details.